Messages on macOS Sonoma (14.4.1) does not record voice message
I can reproduce this 100% of the time.
The orange microphone icon in the menu bar is there and shows no error while I am trying to record a voice message in Messages. Reproducing the recording has no audio, and the waveform is flat. I am on an M3 Max MacBook Pro.
If this is just my machine, what can I do to troubleshoot and possibly resolve?
Please know that due to recent bad experience, calling Apple Support will be the last resort.

This works as expected for me on a 16" M2 Pro MBP on 14.4.1. Can you record in other applications? Is the Microphone set correctly as an input device in System Settings? Phone support is certainly tedious, because they have no eyes but what you tell them, and they have to go through various hoops. Are you near an Apple Store or other authorised repair shop?

The microphone was set correctly, but already in System Settings it was perceiving no sound at all. I logged out of macOS and logged back in, and it is now working again as if nothing had happened. On Apple Support, they can use screen sharing, thus seeing what the user sees, but there is an increase in bad training overall.
